# How does naming of the controller path work?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I created an Azure Web API on .net core 3.1. I started with the "weatherforecast" api demo.
It works, but I do not understand how the naming of the controller works.

When I rename the Controller to "**DummyController**" then "magically" the path to my api is https://.../**dummy**.  How can this be possible? How does that work?

```
namespace mytestapi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class DummyController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string  Get()
        {
            return "wow it's magic!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you use this way to create your API ?
you can easily inherit APIController which is dedicated for web API development

Comment: @IsmailDiari This is created in the template from Visual Studio!

Comment: you have chosed the wrong template, since you can mention that you need a WebApi Tempate and it will prepare every thing for you

Comment: @IsmailDiari I did  this. I upgraded Visual Studio to 16.8.1 and installed .net core 3.1 LTS SDK. Then you get these templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the following attribute [Route ("[controller]")] and select any name for the controller, your link will be the same name.
For example, you can say that the link to this controller is as follows:
[Route ("TestDummy")]

Comment: Thanks, now I understand! It's actually the square brackets which make the magic.

Answer (score 3):

Route Attribute is a shortcut way to define custom routes without the need to make a global configuration on your **startup** file.
This attribute can accept common pattern among others the controller pattern

```
[Route("[controller]")]
```

so when parsing the root to this controller, it will take the name of the controller class without the suffix **Controller**, for your case **Dummy**.

Comment: Thank you also, I understand now. Actually the square brackets in "[controller]" are doing the magic.

Comment: PS: I'm not happy how Microsoft is doing this, In the templates there is much "magic" without explanation. I would prefer simpler code which is understandable.

Comment: you can refer to the official Microsoft Documenation, you will find everything what you need.